# Emmet shortcut that gives style attribute inside div element?

Tags: html, css, emmet

Is there any special character declaration that directly gives me
`<div style=""></div>` just like in the case of `.container` giving me `<div class="container"></div>` and div#con giving me `<div id="con"></div>`

Also I know there is `div[style]` which gives me `<div style=""></div>`

But I want some special character declaration if any, present?? As my solution!!

Comment: `div[style]` is the answer. If you want to set a value you use the `div[style="value"]` syntax!

Comment: @undefined isn't there any other way using special characters?? like I mentioned above!!

Comment: What do you mean by special characters? Shortcuts?

Answer (score 5):

`[style]` works by itself. It converts to `<div style=""></div>`.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned `div[style]` is the way go. `[style]` will work only in some contexts, e.g. inside `<ul>` `[style]` will result in `<li style=""></li>`.

Another option (based on the editor you use) is to define your own emmet abbreviation in `snippets.json`, e.g.

```
{
      "html": {
                abbreviations: {
                                 "@": "div[style]",
                },
      },
}
```

See details in emmet docs [here](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/).

Answer (score 2):

As well as only needing `[style]` to produce `<div style=""></div>`, you can also include style properties.
`[style=background-image:]` gives `<div style="background-image:"></div>`.

Although not much help for single lines, it saves time when producing multiple divs, e.g. `[style=background-image:]*5` gives

```
<div style="background-image:"></div>
<div style="background-image:"></div>
<div style="background-image:"></div>
<div style="background-image:"></div>
<div style="background-image:"></div>
```

You can even add values and multiple properties using [], so
`.box1>.box2[style][width=200px][height=100px]*5` gives

```
<div class="box1">
  <div class="box2" style="" width="200px" height="100px"></div>
  <div class="box2" style="" width="200px" height="100px"></div>
  <div class="box2" style="" width="200px" height="100px"></div>
  <div class="box2" style="" width="200px" height="100px"></div>
  <div class="box2" style="" width="200px" height="100px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div style></div>` is one of Global HTML attribute specifies an inline CSS style for an element. You can only use it to manipulate on that tag.

[check this link out](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @undefined oh sorry, I missed this part "div[style]".